# If $A$ and $C$ are independent events, then $P((A \ and \ C)|B) = P(A|B)*P(C|B) $

Tags: probability

If $A$ and $C$ are independent events (with respect to each other), and B is some arbitrary event, then is it true that $P((A \ and \ C)|B) = P(A|B)*P(C|B) $? I'm trying to prove this as part of the Markov model for part of speech tagging for natural language processing.

$A$ and $C$ being independent is equivalent to the following:
1) $P(A \ and \ C) = P(A)*P(C) $
2)  $P(A|C) = P(A) $
3)  $P(C|A) = P(C) $

What I need to show is even some other event $B$, it is the case that $P((A \ and \ C)|B) = P(A|B)*P(C|B) $. Suggestions? Is it even true?

Comment: It is not true.  Suppose you are tossing two fair coins.  Let $A$ be the event "first coin is $H$", $C$ the event "second coin is $H$".  $A,C$ are independent. Then let $B$ be the event "the two coins come up the same".  Then $P(A\cap C|B)=\frac 12$.  But $P(A|B)=\frac 12= P(C|B)$ so the r.h. is $\frac 14$.